# How to set to int value null? Java Android

Tags: java, android, null, integer, int

which is the best way to set already defined **int** to **null**?

```
private int xy(){
    int x = 5;
    x = null; //-this is ERROR
    return x;
}
```

so i choose this

```
private int xy(){
    Integer x = 5;
    x = null; //-this is OK
    return (int)x;
}
```

Then i need something like :

```
if(xy() == null){
    // do something
}
```

And my second question can i safely cast Integer to int?

Thanks for any response.

Comment: Write a class to wrap the integer and add a boolean called “invalid“ and set it to true whenever the integer should be null. Now you can check if the integer is invalid when calling it. You could also throw an exception when getInt() gets called but “invalid“ is true. Also you could do that as a generic class to avoid doing a class for every single primitive datatype.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case, I would avoid using `null` all together.

Just use `-1` as your `null`

If you need `-1` to be an acceptable (not null) value, then use a `float` instead.  Since all your real answers are going to be integers, make your null `0.1`

Or, find a value that the `x` will never be, like `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or something.

Comment: I think using a float instead of an int where all possible values are actually integers is really ugly.

Answer (score 12):

You can't. `int` is a primitive value type - there's no such concept as a `null` value for `int`.

You can use `null` with `Integer` because that's a *class* instead of a primitive value.

It's not really clear what your method is trying to achieve, but you simply can't represent `null` as an `int`.

Comment: and if i cast Integer to int, can i then ask (int x == null)?

Comment: If you try casting a `null` `Integer` to `int`, then you'll get a `NullPointerException` _at the cast._

Comment: so it is now way how to do it... thanks

Answer (score 6):

Only objects can be null. Primitives (like `int`) can't.

> can i safely cast Integer to int?

You don't need a cast, you can rely on auto-unboxing. However it may throw a NullPointerException:

```
Integer i = 5;
int j = i; //ok

Integer k = null;
int n = k; //Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method compiles, but will throw NullPointerException when trying to unbox the Integer...

The choice between Integer and int depends on what you are trying to achieve. Do you really need an extra state indicating "no value"? If this is a legitimate state, use Integer. Otherwise use int.